# Maven: Excluding EE API from WAR

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

The thing is I am using Hibernate 4.3 in my web application which causes the following artifact to be included into WAR:

```
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
```

As it follows from the dependency hierarchy this artifact is required by the Hibernate-core:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I manually included it in my POM with Provided scope and it was then excluded from the WAR assembly.

I am questioning how to exclude all container provided APIs from the build?

Apparently, solution which is not container-specific would be the best though at least Glassfish hack is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a scope for such things like:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are really sure that hibernate core does not need it (I'm not sure about it) you need to do an exclusion.
Furthermore i have my doubts cause in the above artifact there a some Exceptions defined so you shouldn't exclude them. The question is in which container do you use it? Does this container already provide JPA ?

Comment: I am running Glassfish, the latest one.So you say that because I am not referencing these exception classes I am fine but whenever I do my app would fail?